Facing issue in using recoilstate liberary
I have been working on a project and its keep showing me an error on runtime given below:
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'ReactCurrentDispatcher' of '{imported module [project]/nodemodules/next/dist/compiled/react/index.js [app-client] (ecmascript)}.default.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED' as it is undefined.

I am using nextjs 15 and react 19. I tried downgrade react as well as remove and reinstall node_modules but it keeps showing me the same error.

Provide fallback for an undefined object. Also, using __SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED is not safe.  Hopefully this solved your problem.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
